# How to host an Apache based site alongside an IIS based site - two domains, one IP?

Tags: apache, iis, dns, windows-server

I've inherited a simple small business network which has a single SBS 2003 server running Exchange. It's currently set up so that the domain name `mail.company.com` maps to the server IP, so email can be accessed outside the network.

I don't want to mess with the SBS 2003 setup too much, however, I would like for them to be able to host `intranet.company.com` on the same IP, but mapped to a machine running their Apache-based intranet site so that 'road warriers' can access it too (it would basically become a public website).

We have a single static IP address, an all-in-one firewall/gateway/router and a single Windows SBS 2003 server with DNS and DHCP. The Apache machine is just a Windows 7 box on the network.

Assuming application-level security is as good as it will be for now, so that turning their intranet application into a website application has minimal risk for them, what should I be looking at to actually make it work? Thanks!

(Originally posted on ServerFault, but more relevant here!)

PS I should say that SBS 2003 runs IIS 6.0 and I know that if the Apache machine was listening on port 80 instead of the SBS machine, it would be easy to setup up using virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Application Request Routing on IIS 7 or above allows to create 'server farms' which can be configured to work in a similar way to virtual hosts on Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly its tricky with one static IP, you can use alternative ports but that is a very messy work around.

If IIS is only hosting mail.company.com then my advise would be lock that down to SSL HTTPS on port 443 and then redirect port 80 to the Apache machine for the internet.company.com website. Webmail should not be unsecure anyway as it causing huge issues with ActiveSync, etc.

Any questions let me know.

Charles